# Getting pynodes geometric node to work

Tags: pynodes, add-on

I downloaded the geometric node from git, and copied it in the addon folder of blender 2.67. Tried with 2.67b and a self-compiled svn version, in both, I can't enable it in the user preferences. Does anyone know how to get it to work ? I didn't find any readme.

Edit, more info :

- I downloaded geometry_nodes from https://www.gitorious.org/blender-trunk/addons/trees/geometry_nodes/py/scripts/addons/geometry_nodes
- Extracted the folder geometry_nodes in my ~/.config/blender/2.67/scripts/addons/ folder
- it appears in user preferences under add-ons but I can't activate it. Launching Blender from the command-line doesn't give any help (no error given in output)
- Trying to launch *init*.py gives following error in the console :

> .config/blender/2.67/scripts/addons/geometry_nodes/parameter.py", line
>   433, in register_mod_pass
>       from geometry_nodes import modifiers 
>   ImportError: cannot import name modifiers

Comment: I get the following error `from geometry_nodes import modifiers 
ImportError: cannot import name modifiers` do you?

Comment: Can you add more info to your question.

Comment: @zeffi : yes. CharlesL : updated question with all I could get.

Comment: The first time I run it, this error also shows: `File "...\addons\geometry_nodes\modifiers.py", line 47, in __init__ raise TypeError("Expected TypeSpec datatype")`

Comment: Alot of people are having this problem it seems http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?283098-Blender-2-67-Pynodes

Comment: Zeffi : yes I also had that problem.

Comment: I had a look to the forum link, yes indeed I think nobody managed to get it to work. Problem is, it's in the official doc (the add-on) but there is nowhere any explanation on how it works and it doesn't even work with the official release (tested 2.67a and b). Could someone with contact to the programmer (Brecht ?) ask him how it is supposed to work ? I mean, it's a really powerfull feature, it did cost a nice amount of money to the blender foundation, would be a shame to let it fall in ruin,  or just use 10% of it's potential with only renderer.

Comment: Lukas Tönne implemented this, you can contact him. But do note that this is just a proof of concept to show pynodes work, I doubt it's intended to ever make it into Blender in this form.

Comment: Should this be considered off topic? - if we have questions about random branches on github from users wanting to test... at some point this could be nonconstructive. See: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic

Comment: This is about blender as it's one of the only link to an example in the official doc of 2.67. Most programmer can't get their feet wet in a new API with just the API Doc. I think the python programmer community should get support too, even if we are not pro.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The version of geometry_nodes as of [commit edbdbc8fea539](https://www.gitorious.org/blender-trunk/addons/commit/edbdbc8fea539c0d7b50c1dd525514000d484fc2) does a small check that isn't actually really used yet. This looks to be part of a work-in-progress that is as of yet uncompleted. To get these nodes running you'll have to modify modifiers.py and comment out or remove lines 46 and 47:

```
#if not isinstance(datatype, TypeSpec):
#    raise TypeError("Expected TypeSpec datatype")
```

After this (re-)start blender, enable the addon and play with the geometry nodes :)

Note that as of this writing the above mentioned commit is the latest and the only one in 24 days. Looks very much like current development is on hold.

A small screenshot of geometry nodes in the node editor:

[image: Geometry Nodes in Node Editor]

Comment: **Confirmed**. This works. http://i.stack.imgur.com/ODGMd.png

Comment: Hmm, but as expected, not everything works properly yet, as geometry nodes are very much in development still :) But you can add the nodes!

Any further fixes should be really handled as part of the development process :)

Comment: yes, see brecht's comment on the question above. It is very shaky but it works. :)

Comment: @zeffii tried in *2.66* and *2.67a* and works

Comment: this system won't allow me to award the bounty for another 8 hours, but I can now load that addon too.

Comment: It doesn't appear possible to add the geometry node itself to the NodeTree, but perhaps ideasman42 is right this is a little off topic and maybe even too localized at this stage. Either way, exciting stuff.

Answer (score 2):

As brecht noted correctly, this addon is a proof-of-concept and far from finished. There is a lot of WIP code and it's unlikely to run out of the box. The current branch is somewhat in the process of refactoring.

I've been testing a number of concepts regarding pynodes here (idref links to datablocks, node groups, converter system for parsing node trees) which works very nicely for the most part.

The big TODO is the actual design of a geometry processor, i.e. how geometry data is stored and how nodes can properly address lists to be both flexible and not too complicated. In the meantime this addon must be considered unfinished/broken ...

Comment: nevertheless this addon is very interesting conceptually and codewise, Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Lukas. Please let us know when it's ready :)